# Android - FirebaseApp / Firebase-Initialization is not starting

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement the Firebase-Messaging plugin into my Android-App.
I've started with the "quickstart-android-master/messaging"-example from github: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

This works for me!
Log-Output:

```
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization
D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
I/FirebaseInitProvider﹕ FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

> But if I want to implement the Plugin
>   "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2" into my app, the
>   **FirebaseApp isn't initialized**! So the FirebaseApp plugin isn't starting! - No Log or token received!

I've also added apply plugin to build.gradle file in "app"-directory:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the google-services plugin to build.gradle in the "root" directory:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

> Problems could be:

- AndroidAnnotations, Proguard, Product flavors...

Comment: Have you created app on firebase console ?

Comment: can you show your gradle file content

Comment: yes, I've created it on firebase console! And I also have used my package-name in the example.

Comment: Are you simply judging firebase initialization through the logs or did you try to get the instance in the app ?

Comment: Could it be a conflict with AndroidAnnotations (http://androidannotations.org/) ?

Comment: @Shubhank, I go trough the logs. If I want to get the Token in the Activity, I get this error: "FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist."

Comment: would you try creating the app from scratch? here is a [tutorial](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/06/Implementing-FCM-(-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-)-in-Android-App) i did for it

Comment: Thx. I've done it like in the tutorial. It's very strange.

Comment: Or there could be also a problem with "proguard", but I'm not sure. And I've tested everything...

Comment: Assuming that you have added the google-services.json file to your project. It may be the device has an old version of Google Play services.

Comment: Thx Arthur, for your comment. Yes I've added the google-service.json file. And you are right, this could be a problem, but the example APP from github works on this phone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My problem was the "Manifest Merger".
If I use the

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and

```
tools:node="replace"
```

in the Application Tag of the Manifest, the FirebaseApp will not be initialized!

> If you use **replace** attr on **tools:node** it will replace your
>   lower priority declaration with the annotated one (see more
>   [here](https://www.google.com/url?hl=de&q=http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger%23TOC-tools:node-markers&source=gmail&ust=1467350364335000&usg=AFQjCNFz4sG41XUclzsebJliyKNW1J1fkg)). You should use **merge** or **merge only** attributes
>   instead.

## So what I've exactly done:

This doesn't work:

```
<application
            android:name="xxx"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TemplateStyle"
            tools:node="replace">
```

this works:

```
<application
            android:name="xxx"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/application_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TemplateStyle">
            <!-- tools:node="replace"-->
```

> If you want to overwrite or replace some attributes, use `tools:replace` instead!

Comment: So I have to remove tool in order to fine working of firebase?

Comment: Currently i have updated to tools:replace="android:name" instead of tools:node="replace". hope that help

Comment: @ManuelSchmitzberger Hi Manuel, could you please tell us what is this 'Manifest Merger' and where do we find these lines please?

Comment: @2ndGAB you can find the link for the description in the answer above. Normally you don't need this so called "Manifest Merger", only if you're using "productFlavors", you want to override a SDK Manifest or something like that. It is declared in the AndroidManifest!

Comment: I dont get it, in Manifest what needs to be added actually? Can you give complete example??

Comment: where i can find tools:node="replace" i don;t have thin in my menifest file

Comment: @DarshanKhatri, if you don't use the node-tool in your Manifest, then this should not be your problem!

Comment: Yes You are right ,I have Solved it by just reinstalling the app :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case these permissions were missing in Android Manifest file:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.app.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.app.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This close the issue for me:

- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
- implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` 
then reinstall the app

Answer (score 0):

Another sign there are problems are logcat lines like this

```
FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
```

Check google-service.json, it should have your apk sha1 in it:

apk: sha1

```
SHA1: 4E:AA:54:E0:08:93:C6:CB:7B:8C:74:1E:2A:55:E7:60:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

google-service.json:

```
            "certificate_hash": "4eaa54e00893c6cb7b8c741e2a55e760a5XXXXXX"
```

Delete the whole Android project in firebase, add it again and add your apk sha1.
If your sha1 key changes (ie new app) delete the Android project again and start fresh.

In the past, in anger, I added sha256 and also tried setting up Android Device Verification, SafetyNet etc, none of these are needed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, add the following:

com.google.firebase:firebase-core before com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging

```
dependences {

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'

}
```

Comment: this does not help to me