# FCM - onTokenRefresh() is never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the [setup process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) as mentioned for Firebase Cloud Messaging. But somehow onTokenRefresh is never called.

Following are changes in this regard:

app's `build.gradle:`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project's `build.gradle:`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    <service
        android:name="com.blynq.app.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.blynq.app.services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i("FCM", "Token refreshed - " + token);
        registerTokenWithServer(token);
    }
}
```

Logs state `I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful`, but but onTokenRefresh() is not executed.

I sure am missing something, but unable to understand where.

EDIT: Happening only with emulators, android device worked fine with the above settings.

Comment: try uninstalling the application before installing it again.
ps: only the first action "INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" is correct. you can remove the second.

Comment: Tried reinstalling, did not work

Comment: Have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37831267/1739882

Comment: @ChintanSoni - I am not using tools:node="replace" anywhere in my application tag.

Comment: Just found out this is happening only with emulators, android device worked fine with the above settings.

Comment: @jay are you using tools namespace in manifest ?

Comment: `onTokenRefresh()` will only get called when the token changes. There is a good chance your app already generated a token. You can either remove the app data/reinstall the app or also read the token in your MainActivity.onCreate with `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase FCM force onTokenRefresh() to be called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454501/firebase-fcm-force-ontokenrefresh-to-be-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FCM clients require devices running Android 2.3 or higher that also
>   have the Google Play Store app installed, or an emulator running
>   Android 2.3 with Google APIs.