# Firebase Android - Skipping initialization

Tags: android, firebase, initialization, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently implementing an Android app, which uses Firebase Cloud Messaging.
I've implemented everything according to the tutorial on the Firebase page.

However, whenever I try to run my app it seems like the Firebase initialization fails. Both, on an emulator and on a real device I get this debug message:

```
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10010
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
```

It doesn't call the `InstanceIDListener`.
And it strangely worked with the emulator once.

Comment: Can you share your entire FCM code here?

Comment: Have you overridden any part of the default manifest merge processing?  Similar error messages in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37724761/4815718.

Comment: It seems like the problem was that the onTokenRefresh() method was not called when the app was starting and I thought that firebase doesnt work then. However, I simply called "FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()" in the MainActivity and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following to your android manifest:

```xml
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess you missed:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp